# PHP: OCR of picture with text in a table into a database

Tags: php, gd, ocr

I have a picture of a table with data in it, which is generated newly every day. I want to "parse" every line and every cell of this picture and transfer the written text in this picture to a database. The layout is fixed and never changes. So I can refer to the same positions in the picture every day.

I'm using managed webspace with PHP 5.6.0 stable with standard extensions. It is a managed server without root access.

So I have following questions:

1) Do I have to get a vServer with root access for OCR with PHP or is there another solution for hosted only webspace?

2) Do I have to crop AND save the lines and cells of the picture if I want to OCR it, or is there a way to make the OCR for every line and cell with coordinates  without cropping and saving seperate images?

Thank you,
best regards.

Comment: This seems like over kill. Why not just create a PDF instead and then use a PDF parser, it'll save you tons of time and overhead. Not to mention PHP OCR is not perfect.

Comment: I just tried a demo of PDF Parser, with the image converted into a PDF. This doesn't work. I guess PDF Parser can only extract written text out of the PDF code - not OCR text out of an image. My source is an image - this is not alterable.

Comment: Can you share a picture sample, preferably in original quality and resolution?